# custom message if there isnt any record to show in django-template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Hello there im trying to show a custom message like "Doesnt exists" if there isnt really any record to show
and ignore having `None` in the template for empty records

**Template :**

```
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right ">
                        <label style="color : blue;" class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right size_Style"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : blue;" aria-hidden="true"></i> knowledge cost :</label>
                        <span class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right colorfull">
                            {{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost|safe }}
                        </span>
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right ">
                        <label style="color : blue;" class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right size_Style"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : blue;" aria-hidden="true"></i> knowledge cost percemtage :</label>
                        <span class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right colorfull">
                            {{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost_percent }}
                        </span>
                        
                    </div>
```

based on the given HTML the first Field would Be `None` becuase i dont have any record for it in my `db`
, so is there any more efficient way than using `if` for each record ?

i tried this method for all to handle any empty record

```
{% if special_knowledge.knowledgecost %}
{{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost|safe }}
{% else %}
Doesnt exist
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use Django's built-in `default_if_none` [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) for this.

E.g:

```
{{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost|default_if_none:"nothing" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of: you could also use ([Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty))

```
{% if special_knowledge.knowledgecost %}
{{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost|safe }}
{% empty %}
Doesnt exist
{% endif %}
```

But that is nearly the same :D

You can use the `default` filter. ([Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#default))

```
{{ special_knowledge.knowledgecost|safe|default:"Doesnt exist" }}
```